# Add Additional Index to Select Query & Fetch result using greater than Index ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which right now I am fetching result by adding a additional index but I want to fetch result using greater than operator to Additional index id

This query gives me this

```
SET @a:=0; 
SELECT @a:=@a+1 additional_id, output.*
FROM (SELECT sum(item_sale +  item_viewed) as totalSum ,item_id FROM items WHERE item_active='1' GROUP BY item_id order by totalSum desc ) output
```

| additional_id | item_id | totalSum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 17 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

But i want to use greater than operator and want result like this if additional_id > 1 then find only 2 result

| additional_id | item_id | totalSum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

How could i achieve this ?

Comment: You are  looking for second and third best seller?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Use your query as subquery, apply according WHERE in outer query.

Comment: Yes I am using load more function and finding best seller is now little bit difficult for me because If fetching via only primary id is very easy but finding best sellers stucked. So, I added additional index , but i am confuse how to get result by additional_id

Comment: @P.Salmon , MySQL Version is 5.7.28 and PHP is 7.40

Comment: @Akina, Can you please post query as subquery. I am totally confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (

-- your query
SELECT @a:=@a+1 additional_id, output.*
FROM (SELECT sum(item_sale +  item_viewed) as totalSum ,item_id FROM items WHERE item_active='1' GROUP BY item_id order by totalSum desc ) output
-- end of your query

CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a:=0) init_variable
) AS subquery
WHERE additional_id > 1
```